# Custom Font in svg

Tags: html, fonts, svg

I would like to use custom fonts in a svg embedded in a web page. With setattribute I can use Arial... fonts. I think those fonts are embedded in the browser and I can use it. But how can I do to use custom fonts? 
In Firefox, when I use in css for exemple @font-face ....

```
@font-face {

                font-family: "ITCGothicBold";
                src: url('fonts/ITCGothicBold.ttf') format("truetype");

}
```

that font-family works in a Html web page.

On the other hand, for exemple, in the svg text:

```
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="ITCGothicBold.ttf" font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="72.83333" x="74.75" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">HELLO</text>
```

I would like to use for exemple ITCGothicBold.ttf. Using setattribute I can put ITCGothicBold.ttf in the font_family attribute but nothing change: the HELLO text is not changing. 
Does anyone know how to work with custom font in svg embedded in a web page? Thanks

NOTE: The full code I have used is:

```
<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face {

                font-family: "ITCGothicBold.ttf";
                src: url('fonts/ITCGothicBold.ttf') format("truetype");

}</style>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <title>Calque 1</title>
  <text fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" x="75.75" y="72.83333" id="svg_1" font-size="24" font-family="ITCGothicBold.ttf" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve">HELLO</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: try this: put all attributes in style ex.<text style="...">HELLO</text>

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 8):

You can change fonts in svgs just as you do in css.

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: font;
        src: url(font.woff);
    }
    svg{
        font-family: font, fallBackFonts, sans-serif;
    }
</style
```

Though I would suggest you define it more verbosely for better compatibility. That way you can provide a variety of fallbacks.

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'font'; 
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('location/of/font.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
         url('location/of/font.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('location/of/font.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('location/of/font.svg#webfont') format('svg'); 
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

Services that provide font conversions (for the eot, woff, truetype, and svg files) are...
https://github.com/briangonzalez/fontprep
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

That being said, if you REALLY want to assign the font IN the svg you would add the attribute font-family just like you have. Though I wouldn't include the file extension (.ttf) in the naming scheme.

Comment: Hello @Quinn,
Can you please let me know how I can use server's font by URL?
Like this: http://myserverurl.com/Fonts/fontname.eot
I have tried your solution but not get any luck.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question Kalpesh. Are you sure you are using the correct URL?

Comment: Yes, I am using correct url of the font. If I am use the path of folder directory then it's work fine.  But when I try with any font url like ny last comment then it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I referenced an SVG font from another SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000">

  <defs>
    <font-face>
      <font-face-src>
        <font-face-uri href="file:///.../DejaVuSans.svg"/>
      </font-face-src>
    </font-face>
  </defs>

  <text x="0" y="400" font-family="DejaVu Sans" font-size="200">
    Abc
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is deprecated and being removed from browsers