# How can we set custom fonts in SVG image?

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I have added the custom fonts in stylesheet and want to include in SVG but it doesn't load custom fonts. How can custom fonts to be added in SVG? Here is following SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1024" height="768">
<defs>

        <link href="fonts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>

</defs>
<g>
    <title>background</title>
    <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas_background" fill="#fff"/>
    <g id="canvasGrid" display="none">
        <rect id="svg_2" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gridpattern)"/>
    </g>
</g>
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
<g>
    <title>background</title>
    <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="100%" width="100%" y="-1" x="-1"/>
    <g display="none" id="canvasGrid">
        <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="svg_2"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <title>background</title>
    <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas_background" fill="#fff"/>
    <g id="canvasGrid" display="none">
        <rect id="svg_2" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gridpattern)"/>
    </g>
</g>
 <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <text opacity="0.65" stroke="#000000" transform="matrix(0.323552, 0, 0, 1.60358, 525.282, -195.77)" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="gallardo" font-size="153.6" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="svg_2" y="482.50282" x="-67.52708" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000">We bring your ideas to print</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Font in svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599755/custom-font-in-svg)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905026/cross-browser-embedded-font-in-svg-image